# Cannot Send SMS Customer?

Tags: laravel, controller, sms

Sending SMS Not working With controller in Laravel .

I've done everything and I don't know to do anything else.

I am trying to send an SMS using php functio but I am Not getting anything.

but I don't know. Is there something missing or not?

This is a API SMS Method

Showing Error : Undefined variable $ch

You can see my code below.

```
    //Start Store Method
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $registration_id = IdGenerator::generate(['table' => 'hajjapplications', 'field' => 'registration_id', 'length' => 6, 'prefix' => date('24')]);
    $cfname = $request->input('cfname');
    $cnicno = $request->input('cnicno');
    $cdob = $request->input('cdob');
    $cpassno = $request->input('cpassno');
    $adno = $request->input('adno');
    $street = $request->input('street');
    $village = $request->input('village');
    $town = $request->input('town');
    $division = $request->input('division');
    $district = $request->input('district');
    $mob1 = $request->input('mob1');
    $lline = $request->input('lline');
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $prehajj = $request->input('prehajj');
    $nbank = $request->input('nbank');
    $branch = $request->input('branch');
    $accno = $request->input('accno');
    $accname = $request->input('accname');

    $rules = [
        'cfname' => 'required',
        'cnicno' => 'required',
        'cdob' => 'required',
        'cpassno' => 'required',
        'street' => 'required',
        'village' => 'required',
        'town' => 'required',
        'division' => 'required',
        'district' => 'required',
        'mob1' => 'required',
    ];

    $customMessages = [
        'cfname.required' => 'The Full Name field is required.',
        'cnicno.required' => 'The NIC field is required.',
        'cdob.required' => 'The Date of Birth field is required.',
        'cpassno.required' => 'The Passport field is required.',
        'cnicno.unique' => 'The NIC is already exists, please check your NIC.',
        'cpassno.unique' => 'The Passport No already exists, please check your Passport No.',
        'street.required' => 'The Street field is required.',
        'village.required' => 'The Village field is required.',
        'town.required' => 'The Town field is required.',
        'division.required' => 'The Division field is required.',
        'district.required' => 'The District field is required.',
        'mob1.required' => 'The Mobile field is required.'
    ];

    $validate = $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);

    if ($validate) {
        $isInsertSuccess = HajjForm::insert([
            'registration_id' => $registration_id,
            'cfname' => $cfname,
            'cnicno' => $cnicno,
            'cdob' => $cdob,
            'cpassno' => $cpassno,
            'adno' => $adno,
            'street' => $street,
            'village' => $village,
            'town' => $town,
            'division' => $division,
            'district' => $district,
            'mob1' => $mob1,
            'lline' => $lline,
            'email' => $email,
            'prehajj' => $prehajj,
            'nbank' => $nbank,
            'branch' => $branch,
            'accno' => $accno,
            'accname' => $accname,

        ]);


        if ($isInsertSuccess) {
            $access_token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUfgsFSdghjkhJHjhKJHjhzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJkbXJjYWhhamphZEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJ0eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzVG9rZW4iLCJleHAiOjE3MDE0Mjc3MDMsImlhdCI6MTcwMTM0MTMwM30.b8Mm8oMDLl-_dQB9dgfpbVIgdeJ8E6y4CG7N_aOB_Z3A5jTGSBjY7Y5d5vcnzyhoxfwWQxridlC74aqGHm2nIQ';

            $post_data = [
                "numbers" => $mob1, // Assuming $mob1 is already defined
                "content" => "2024 Reference XXX Application. Reg. No - $registration_id Your application is being processed & it is pending. Once the process is completed, we will confirm you.",
            ];


            $username = "XXXX@gmail.com";
            $password = "XXXXXXX";
            $text = urlencode("2024 Reference Hajj Application. Reg. No - $registration_id Your application is being processed & it is pending. Once the process is completed, we will confirm you.");
            $curl = 'https://bsms.hutch.lk/api/sendsms';
            $curl .= "?id=$username&pw=$password&to=$mob1&content=$text";

            $curl = curl_init($curl);
            $response = Http::get('https://bsms.hutch.lk/api/login');

            // Set cURL options as needed
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); // Use CURLOPT_POST instead of $curlOPT_POST
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Accept: */*',
                'X-API-VERSION: v1',
                'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token
            ]);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));

            $response = curl_exec($curl);

            if ($response) {
                echo "SMS Sent to $mob1";
                $notification = [
                    'message' => 'Application Registered Successfully',
                    'alert-type' => 'success',
                ];
                return redirect()->back()->with($notification);
        // return redirect()->away("$curl&user=dmrcahajjad@gmail.com&password=nk#%23QQ&mobile=$mob1&message=hello&sender=MRCAHJJ&type=3&template_id=12");

            } else {
                echo curl_error($curl);
            }

            // Close cURL session
            curl_close($curl);
        }
    }
}
//End Method
```

Comment: You're trying to use `$ch` in your last `curl_setopt`, but your curl variable is named `$curl`

Comment: @aynber

i will change curl_setopt $ch but connote send message to cutomer

Comment: You're checking for a response, but not what the response contains. What does `$response` contain?

Comment: @aynber I don't know that? `$response`

Comment: That would be good to check. Just because `$response` isn't false, doesn't mean that it was successful. You may be getting an error back from the other side. Try `var_dump($response);` to see what it contains

Comment: @aynber  which place i add this `var_dump($response)` ?

Comment: Right after `$response = curl_exec($curl);` or `if ($response) {` would be a good place

Comment: @aynber Displaying a Error : 
`object(Illuminate\Http\Client\Response)#269 (4)`

`"response":protected=> object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)#330 (6)`

Comment: That would be the response from `$response = Http::get('https://bsms.hutch.lk/api/login');`, not the response from `$response = curl_exec($curl);`, so move the var_dump further down. I'd suggest picking *either* Http::client **or** curl, don't use both for the same thing.

Comment: @aynber I changed `$response = Http::get('https://bsms.hutch.lk/api/login');`. **but not recive sms**

Comment: Okay, once again, we're trying to find out what the response is from your curl command. Delete the `Http::get` line, you're not using it properly, and you're using curl directly instead. You can convert it from curl to the Http client once you figure out what's going on. Add `var_dump($response);` **after** your `$response = curl_exec($curl);` to see what it contains

Comment: @aynber. Please check this one [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77589925/cannot-send-or-recive-sms-in-laravel]

Answer (score 0):

`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` - This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...', if you use `'Content-Type: application/json`

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));
```

Comment: This is a SMS Gate Way PHP. I want to convert to controller

$ch = curl_init('https://bsms.hutch.lk/api/sendsms');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
 CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
 CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
 'Content-Type: application/json',
 'Accept: */*',
 'X-API-VERSION: v1',
 'Authorization: Bearer '.$access_token
 ),
 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($post_data)
 ));
 $response = curl_exec($ch);